# Is There Anyway to Get Cross-Platform Gamepad Input in C Without Something Like Allegro?

Tags: c, cross-platform, gamepad

Is it possible to get cross-platform gamepad input in C. All I was able to find was [Allegro](https://liballeg.org/) but I want something that just gets gamepad input. Is there anything like this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with game pad input once you receive it?

Comment: Which gamepads do you want to support? On which platforms? SDL supports many platforms and has excellent compatibility with a large number of popular gamepads, I'd start there.